# Access informix using C# inside docker container

Tags: c#, docker, db2, informix

I am working on migrating a NET application that accesses an Informix database so that it can run in a Docker container.
I have done a POC and when I run it on my local machine it works correctly. But when I want to run the same application inside a container, an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'db2app.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.UnsafeNativeMethods.DB232.SQLFreeConnAttribsADONET(DB2SQLGetConnAttribsADONETParams& pParam)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.ConnSettingsFromXmlConfig.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.ConnSettingsFromXmlConfig.Dispose()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection 
connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, 
DB2ConnSettingsInternal& pSettingsInternal, Boolean bAttach, Boolean 
pushDownStrAppended)
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
at ConsoleInformix.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

The container is based on the image:
    microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803

The main application to migrate is a Web API project (.NET Framework 4.7.2)

Examining NuGet packages for IBM.DataDB2 warns:
"NOTICE - This package requires the IBM DB2 client software to be installed locally and available on your %PATH% environment variable"

But I have not managed to solve how to perform unattended or silent installation of the IBM client in the container. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you using Db2 or Informix?  Although both are IBM products, these are not the same DBMS, and they have different clients.

Comment: I am using an Informix Data Base and I've been using the IBM.Data.DB2 (IBM Data Server .NET Provider) for two years, following these recommendations:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/index.html

Thanks

Comment: Which db2 client have you tried? . Which exact filename did you download from IBM? The full Db2 client for Windows installs just fine silently with response file although there is a learning curve. Same for the Db2  runtime client. Have you tried installing manually inside container first, to verify operation?

Comment: I downloaded the "ibm_data_server_client_winx64_v11.1.zip" and run setup.exe
It is the same installer that we use to install the client drivers on localhost

I executed the docker container in interactive mode and executed Setup.exe from the command line but nothing happened.
I've read about running a silent install with a response file but I don't know how to configure it and if I have to run it with the same Setup.exe or some other installer

Comment: Study the docs  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/r0011957.html.. Get it working first with response file outside of a container. Then when you have mastered it, try inside container. Be sure to use the trace file option to setup. Exe otherwise problem determination is not possible on Windows . The container needs latest Microsoft setup installer. If you have container specific Db2 setup issues try latest 11.1.4.4 client.