# Access Informix using C# (Net Core 2.2) inside a Windows Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, db2, informix

I am working on migrating a **NET Core** application that accesses an Informix database so that it can run in a **Windows Docker container**. I have done a POC and when I run it on my local machine it works correctly. But when I want to run the same application inside a container, an exception is thrown:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in IBM.Data.DB2.Core.dll
An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in 
IBM.Data.DB2.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll' or one of its dependencies: The 
specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The container is based on the image: microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base

The main application to migrate is a Web API project (**NET Core 2.2**)

I am using the **IBM.Data.DB2.Core** NuGet package (version 1.3.0.100)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access informix using C# inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302931/access-informix-using-c-sharp-inside-docker-container)

Comment: How are you building your application?  `dotnet publish`?

Comment: I am just running it with F5 (Debug > Start debugging). In the Dockerfile that was automatically created we can see:
...
RUN dotnet restore "WebApiCoreInDockerPOC/WebApiCoreInDockerPOC.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApiCoreInDockerPOC"
RUN dotnet build "WebApiCoreInDockerPOC.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApiCoreInDockerPOC.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
...

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this?  I am trying to use the Informix.Net.Core library and run my app from Docker as well and I keep getting.

Dependency unixODBC with minimum version 2.3.1 is required.
Unable to load shared library 'iclit09b.dll' or one of its dependencies.

I have installed unixodbc and unixodbc-dev and it makes no difference.